# What's the purpose of the "Secondary Connection String" on Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azureservicebus

I thought I could use it to implement some kind of redundancy, but the URI is almost the same as the Primary one (the only difference is the SharedAccessKey).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the azure services like `azure storage` / `azure iot hub` / `azure service bus` has 2 connection strings / access keys.

The main purpose is that in some cases, if the `primary connection string` is revealed, you need to rotate it. At this time, to avoid `downtime of you app`, you can replace the `primary connection string` with the `secondary connection string`.

You can also refer to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-keys-manage?tabs=azure-portal#manually-rotate-access-keys) for more details(It's for `azure storage`, but it can be also used for `azure service bus`).